# Using socat to relay one TTY stream to multiple TCP/IP destinations, plus to one 'sniffer' program

Tags: tcp, tty, netcat, socat

Using an embedded Linux development board, I need to put together a widget that does the following:

- Reads packets in via physical serial port, and relays those packets to a number of IP addresses (up to 20 of them; with IP destinations read from a configuration file).
- Also 'sniff' those serial packets using a custom program, perhaps written in `c`.

As someone with a programming background, the most obvious solution (to me) would be to create a `c` program from scratch to achieve the above. However, as this is something I need to throw together quickly, and because I need an excuse to learn more about existing Linux command-line programs and script writing (which I'm not so good at), I'm wondering if much of this could be achieved with existing command-line programs and a shell script. Then, the only part I write from scratch is my packet sniffer (call it `sniffer.c`).

I understand that `netcat` and `socat` can be used for relaying between devices and addresses, and I have started experimenting with both. The thought occurs to me that I could avoid having to develop and test TCP/IP software by running multiple instances of `socat` to relay serial data from the TTY port to remote IP addresses. Each instance of `socat` could handle a particular remote IP address.

Does this sound feasible, and if so, how could I effectively 'multiplex' a stream from `/dev/ttyS0` (say) as the source for multiple instances of `socat` plus one instance of `sniffer.c`? Could one way be to relay data read from `/dev/ttyS0` to a cache file, and then have my `socat` instances and `sniffer.c` all have a read-only access to that file?

Comment: Hey Trevor. I am researching similar problem. Wondering if you found any solutions since you asked this.

Comment: Hello there. In the end I abandoned the idea of trying to use any standard utilities to achieve this, and wrote everything from scratch in C. I'm just trying to finish off this project right now as it happens.

Comment: Maybe `socat` with `tee` combination can do the trick, but never tried myself. Here is e.g. example of forwarding incoming traffic to both ports https://gist.github.com/mathieue/3505472